# Why 1000 CCD Barcode Contact Scanner can't recognize zero?

Tags: barcode

I have a barcode scanner, named: 1000 CCD Barcode Contact Scanner

I have downloaded the USB driver and the Scanner Manager from CipherLab, but I cant get it work. It works well on windows 7 but doesnot recognize zero char....

For example I want to read this:

```
136936308200450
```

But it reads it:

```
1369363ö82öö45ö
```

With cipherlab scanner manager I can't even connect to the barcode reader. When I click on read the scanner settings it ask me for COM port properties. But I use it on USB.

How could I congifure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is not really an electronics question, I assume your barcode scanner has been set as a virtual keyboard. Your nativity settings / keyboard language is not English as default and hence it reads some characters differently.
Try changing the keyboard language to English.

Looking at its specs, the scanner has multiple interface options. When in keyboard mode, windows only recognises it as a keyboard and usually it interacts with it as a keyboard only. Try changing the scanner's interface mode by the control barcodes usually supplied with scanners. (I'm not sure if you have that or not. Motorola usually supplies control barcodes with their scanners, I'm assuming this scanner has them too. If not in the box, maybe downloadable.)

Comment: Thanky you very much! It saves me! I changed keyboard language and it works well.